# Inverting a single axis plot in R

Tags: r

I plotted a single column in R with the code below

`plot(datanew$cap)`

But what I actually need is that the points on the x-axis should be on the y-axis while the point on the y-axis should be the x-axis. If anyone has an idea on how I can do this, I will greatly apreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plotting via

```
plot(datanew$cap)
```

is basically the same as

```
plot(seq(length(datanew$cap)), datanew$cap)
```

You can use this to your advantage by swapping the arguments (or specifiying x- and y-coordinates explicitly):

```
plot(x=datanew$cap, y=seq(length(datanew$cap)))
```